# Count ticket number in sql

Tags: sql-server

What im trying to do is only display records created for a customer that only has more then one ticketnumber in a certain month.

```
Select name,ticketnumber, title,
description,statename,personname,charge,createdon
from case
Where sum(ticketnumber) > 2 AND createdon >= '2017-01-01' ;
```

i have tried

```
select sum(ticketnumber) AS total
```

and

```
where sum(ticketnumber) > 2
```

Where am i going wrong? `ticketnumber` is a `varchar` data type

The error im getting;

```
Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator.
```

Comment: use `count(ticketnumber)` for strings

Comment: @SqlZim, Thanks , i have tried that,  and im getting `name is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the check to a single month, not just after some date, you can use `dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, createdon )  , 0)` to truncate a date down to the first of a month.

Assuming you are identifying your customer by `personname`:

using `exists()`:

```
select 
    name
  , ticketnumber
  , title
  , description
  , statename
  , personname
  , charge
  , createdon
from [case] as c
where dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, createdon )  , 0) = '20170101'
  and exists (
  select 1
  from [case] as i
  where --createdon >= '2017-01-01'
    dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, createdon )  , 0) = '20170101'
    and i.personname = c.personname
  having count(*) > 1
  )
```

using `in()`

```
select 
    name
  , ticketnumber
  , title
  , description
  , statename
  , personname
  , charge
  , createdon
from [case]
where dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, createdon )  , 0) = '20170101'
  and personname in (
  select personname
  from [case] as i
  where --createdon >= '2017-01-01'
    dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, createdon )  , 0) = '20170101'
  group by personname
  having count(*) > 1
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried your two sql statements and it is bringing back cases that were created before`20170101`

Comment: @AndroidAL Updated to include the `createdon` filter in the outer `select` as well.

Comment: ,Thanks for the help, say i wanted to add a description that was related to a case but that description was from a different table how would i add that new column?

Comment: @AndroidAL You would traditionally use an [**`inner join` or `left join`**](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/joins.php) in your `from` clause e.g. `from [case] as c left join [related_table] as r on c.case_id = r.case_id` and add the columns to your `select`.

Comment: Thanks again , im trying to Group By personname and is not seem to be working?

Comment: @AndroidAL not sure what you are trying to do based on just that statement.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just do this

```
SELECT Total from (select sum(ticketnumber) AS total from case)A 
Where Total>2
```